# How to get id of a tag inside li tag?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I get id of anchor tag specified in li tag?

My code is:

```html
 <li name="cmspage"><a href="#" id ="<?php echo $data ->page_id; ?>"><?php echo $data ->page_title; ?></a></li>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: you want id inside specific li element ?

Comment: Did you try doing some research yourself first? It seems like something that would only take 5 seconds to google.

Comment: Dark Ashelin,Of Course,I couldn't find thats why I came here... :)

Answer (score 1):

From what little you've shown in your question, it would be:

```
var id = $("li[name=cmspage] > a").attr("id");
```

More in the [CSS selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com).

Answer (score 0):

You need to select **li tag together with anchor** as following code :

```
<script>
$(function(){
   var id = $('li a').attr('id');
   alert(id);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `$("li a").attr("id")` :

```js
alert( $("li a").attr("id") )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul><li name="cmspage"><a href="#" id ="id1">Some title</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: Okay, triple simultaneous identical answers :)